# How do I get the top 5 albums of an artist from the Spotify Web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to build a site using ASP.NET MVC 4 and C# to search for the top 5 albums of a musical artist using the Spotify web api.

Here is my code so far:

```
public ActionResult Result(string Artist)
    {
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.spotify.com/");
        // what goes here to authenticate and get the info?

        return View();
    }
```

I can not find information that tells me how to authenticate and then retrieve the information using C#.

**Edit:** I should mention that I am an absolute beginner with this stuff and while I did read the spotify api reference, it did not help me because it does not explain enough detail.

For example the web api user guide talks about GET, POST, etc but does not give any code to help explain how to use it. The only code on there is:

```
$ curl -H "Authorization: Basic Yjc...cK" -d grant_type=refresh_token -d refresh_token=AQD...f0 "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token"

{
    "error": "invalid_client",
    "error_description": "Invalid client secret"
}
```

Which is confusing to me because I don't know where to put it, I don't know what language the code is, etc.

There are no C# examples that I can find. Even the code examples are all javascript which does not help me.

Comment: why not read the Spotify API documentation? 
https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/endpoint-reference/

Comment: I did... It does not help.

Comment: You mention that you read the documentation, but that it didn't help because it "*does not explain enough detail*".  If that's the case, why not ask a question about what you don't understand *specifically*?

Answer (score 0):

You should see this maybe help to you

[TagSearch](https://tagsearch.codeplex.com)

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace TagSearch.Plugins
{
    public class Spotify : IClass
    {
        #region JsonParseData

        public class Rootobject
        {
            public Tracks tracks { get; set; }
        }

        public class Tracks
        {
            public List<Item> items { get; set; }
        }

        public class Item
        {
            public Album album { get; set; }
            public List<Artist> artists { get; set; }
            public int disc_number { get; set; }
            public string name { get; set; }
            public int track_number { get; set; }
        }

        public class Album
        {
            public string href { get; set; }
            public string release_date { get; set; }
            public string release_date_precision { get; set; }
            public List<Image> images { get; set; }
            public string name { get; set; }
        }

        public class Image
        {
            public int height { get; set; }
            public string url { get; set; }
            public int width { get; set; }
        }

        public class Artist
        {
            public string name { get; set; }
        }

        #endregion
        protected Dictionary<String, int> _TempTotal;
        protected Dictionary<String, List<ITag>> _TempTag;
        private object _Lock = new object();
        public Spotify()
        {
            JParse = new System.Text.Json.JsonParser();
            _TempTotal = new Dictionary<string, int>();
            _TempTag = new Dictionary<String, List<ITag>>();
        }
        public override void Search(string Name)
        {
            GetInfo(Name);
        }
        protected override void GetInfo(string Name)
        {
            lock (_Lock)
            {
                _TempTotal.Add(Name, -1);
                _TempTag.Add(Name, new List<ITag>());
            }

            var web = new IWebClient();
            web.DownloadDataCompleted += DownloadDataCompleted;
            web.DownloadDataAsync(new Uri("https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?&type=track&limit=50&q=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(Name.ToLower())), new IWebClient.WebClientState(Name, 1, null));

            while (_TempTotal[Name] != _TempTag[Name].Count) { System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000); }

            OnEvent(Name,_TempTag[Name]);

            _TempTotal.Remove(Name);
            _TempTag.Remove(Name);
            base.GetInfo(Name);
        }
        protected void DownloadDataCompleted(dynamic sender, dynamic e)
        {
            if (e.Result != null)
            {
                string Name = e.UserState.Name;
                switch ((int)e.UserState.State)
                {
                    case 1:
                        var _RootObject = JParse.Parse<Rootobject>(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.Result));
                        _TempTotal[Name] = _RootObject.tracks.items.Count;
                        foreach (var Json in _RootObject.tracks.items)
                        {
                            var web = new IWebClient();
                            web.DownloadDataCompleted += DownloadDataCompleted;
                            web.DownloadDataAsync(new Uri(Json.album.href), new IWebClient.WebClientState(Name, 2, new ITag(this.GetType(), Json.name, Json.album.name, Json.artists[0].name, null, DateTime.MinValue, Json.disc_number, Json.track_number)));
                            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(250);
                        }
                        sender.Dispose();
                        break;

                    case 2:
                        var Json2 = JParse.Parse<Album>(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.Result));
                        e.UserState.State = 3;
                        switch ((string)Json2.release_date_precision)
                        {
                            case "year": e.UserState.Tag.RelaseDate = DateTime.Parse(Json2.release_date + "-01-01"); break;
                            case "month": e.UserState.Tag.RelaseDate = DateTime.Parse(Json2.release_date + "-01"); break;
                            case "day": e.UserState.Tag.RelaseDate = DateTime.Parse(Json2.release_date); break;
                        }
                        sender.DownloadDataAsync(new Uri(Json2.images[0].url), e.UserState);
                        break;

                    case 3:
                        e.UserState.Tag.Cover = e.Result;
                        _TempTag[Name].Add(e.UserState.Tag);
                        sender.Dispose();
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```